# Ruby String Automatically Escaped

Tags: json, ruby

I am pulling JSON data from a website and am trying to output it within another JSON array.

The data is being pulled properly, but when I shove it into the array of my own, the data gets escaped...

Example:

```
"{\n  \"company\": {\n    \"name\": \"SomeName\", \n  \"searching\": false, \n  \"status\": \"LEAD\"\n}"
```

How can I prevent the `\` and `\n` from inserting themselves everywhere?

Comment: a) The escape ( \ ) character isn't really inserted in the string, if you print this string in console, there wouldn't be any of these. That's simply how Ruby displays strings with `"` characters. b) `\n` sign is in the new line character and wasn't inserted either, because it was in the original string already.
Show how you try to parse all this JSON array in your Ruby code please.

Comment: You actually helped me answer my own question by asking how I'm parsing the data... I wasnt! :) Thank you!!